# Laravel how to use $request except on nested array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, request

Is it possible to use **$request->except** on a nested array? This is the request data:

```
    [▼
      "id" => 1
      "products" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "name" => "sample product"
          "date" => "07/04/2022"
          "frequency" => array:1 [ …1]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

My goal is to remove some key value pairs e.g. removing **id**, **date** and **frequency**. My desired result would be:

```
    [▼
      "id" => 1
      "products" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "name" => "sample product"
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

What I've tried so far is to use **Arr:except** function:

```
$request->products = Arr::except($request->products['0'], ['id', 'date', 'frequency']);
```

But this should be applied on all items. Let's say I have two item products, the desired result would be:

```
        [▼
          "id" => 1
          "products" => array:2 [▼
            0 => array:1 [▼
              "name" => "sample product"
            ]
            1 => array:1 [▼
              "name" => "sample product 2"
            ]
          ]
        ]
```

Need your inputs on what's the best approach for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something obvious, could you not just iterate over the `products` in your `$request` object?

```
$filtered = [];

foreach ($request->products as $product) {
    $filtered[] = Arr::except($product, ['id', 'date', 'frequency']);
}

dd($filtered);
```

Resulting in `$filtered` containing:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "products" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "name" => "sample product"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "name" => "sample product 2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

**Update 1**

> I can see that the $request except only works on the top level

Not sure what you mean by this as the above principle works for me.

```
$filtered = [];
foreach ($request->products as $product) {
    $filtered[] = Arr::except($product, ['id', 'date', 'frequency']);
}
$request->merge(['products' => $filtered]);
```

If I supply the above with the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "sample product",
            "date": "07/04/2022",
            "frequency": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "sample product 2",
            "date": "07/04/2022",
            "frequency": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Then do a `dd($request->products);` I get:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "sample product"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "sample product 2"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Yes, this is correct. What I would like is to retain the $request data and not declare a new variable. So instead of declaring $filtered[], it would be directly on the $request. I can see that the $request except only works on the top level.

Comment: @user3233787 Please see my answer update.